# Kafka consumer in test only works with "auto.offset.reset"="earliest"

Tags: java, apache-kafka, integration-testing

I'm struggling to understand my Kafka consumer behaviours in some integration tests.

I have a Spring boot service which uses a default, autowired `KafkaTemplate<String, String>` to produce messages to a topic. In my integration tests, I create a KafkaConsumer in each test:

```
        KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(
            Map.of( ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, KAFKA_CONTAINER.getBootstrapServers(),
                ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "test-consumer-group-" + UUID.randomUUID(),
                ConsumerConfig.GROUP_INSTANCE_ID_CONFIG, UUID.randomUUID().toString() ),
            new StringDeserializer(), new StringDeserializer() );
        consumer.subscribe( topics );
        return consumer;
```

with the intent of having a test flow that looks something like:

1. Create a new consumer for the topics we're testing
2. Perform action under test which sends messages to some topics
3. Poll the topics of interest and verify the messages are there
4. Close consumer

My expectation was that since the default behaviour of a new consumer is to have `auto.offset.reset` set to `latest` I would only get messages sent after I create the consumer, which looks fine in this case. However my consumer never receives any messages! I have to set the consumer to `earliest` - but this is problematic since I don't want messages created by other tests interfering.

The messages don't have any kind of unique identifier on them, which makes consuming the entire topic each time a tricky proposition in terms of test verifications.

I've tried various permutations of auto committing, polling before running the test but after subscribing, manual syncs but nothing seems to work - how can manage my test lifecycle as described above (or is it not possible)?

The kafka instance is managed using TestContainers in case that's relevant.

Comment: I think than when `subscribe()` returns, your consumer is not yet listening, the hand-shake to squeeze it in the consumer group still needs to happen. When it does, every consumer in the group is notified of a _rebalance_, at which moment starting offsets are assigned to each. I guess what happens in your case is that this rebalance happens after you've produced some records. Try to `subscribe(Pattern pattern,                    ConsumerRebalanceListener listener)` and from this one somehow notify your producer thread that it can start.

Comment: You can also use the java admin client to create one specific topic per test, in my experience it tends to make the tests more debuggable, and allows parallel execution if that's desired